# Is Google Encrypted BigQuery capable of querying encrypted data using LIKE operator?

Tags: python, sql, encryption, google-bigquery

I have been doing some research on to implement like operator onto query the encrypted data. I was wondering if Google's Encrypted BigQuery has this functionality implemented?

Comment: Please include some links to Encrypted BigQuery. It's the first time I hear such. Maybe it's just the connector that does this. So this question might be totally off.

Comment: https://github.com/google/encrypted-bigquery-client

Comment: https://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/ Encrypted BigQuery is experimental extension of BigQuery and is implemented based on the prototype cryptDB. It offers client-side encryption for a subset of query types, using encryption building blocks similar to the RND, HOM, and DET used in CryptDB. Their code is available here https://github.com/google/encrypted-bigquery-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Yes, after a fashion (or, NO, if you want the 'full power' of LIKE).

You cannot do straight LIKE query on an *arbitrarily* encrypted string, because there's no way of running comparisons on *arbitrarily* encrypted strings. So you'd need to have decryption ran server side, then LIKE applied. Something like:

```
... WHERE DECRYPT(field, key) LIKE '%SEARCH%'
```

which in this case can't be done since encryption is run in the connector, which would then need to retrieve **all** rows, decrypt them all, and then run the LIKE check.

In some cases it is possible to use LIKE on an encrypted, if you use a special (weaker) encryption that maps symbols in a deterministic way, e.g. "A" will always be converted to "F" (or other calculable-at-runtime value) whatever its position. This means that the encrypted search key, minus any modifier (e.g. %), will be present in the encrypted field.

If this holds, then instead of searching 'ATTACK' in a field that, unencrypted, would be 'ATTACK AT DAWN', you search 'FXXFJR' in a field that, encrypted, is 'FXXFJR FX PFNU'. You can also search '%FX%' and get the same results you'd get by searching '%AT%' on the unencrypted table.

But you need to encrypt the field using a specific algorithm. Rijndael for example wouldn't do at all. Also, the algorithm is inherently weaker; it's actually what's called a shuffle cipher, a more general case of the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) (one could slightly strengthen this implementation at the expense of search time by extending it to be a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher)).

In *this* case there appears to be a specific algorithm you need to encrypt the searchable fields with, which is "SearchWords" (and a second one called "Probabilistic"). If you encrypt a column with that algorithm, it gets passed to

```
https://github.com/google/encrypted-bigquery-client/blob/master/src/query_interpreter.py

def RewriteSearchwordsEncryption(field, literal):
```

and converted to some form which can then be searched. It's unclear whether this works with **any** string (e.g. '%AT DAW%') or if you need to specify one of the words (e.g. 'ATTACK', 'AT' or 'DAWN'; '%TACK' won't work).

Actually, on rereading the code, it *looks* to me as if encrypted searchable fields simply contain also the concatenation of the hashes of the encrypted keywords. You run this kind of search with the 'CONTAINS' keyword.